# Unit testing as documentation and undefined behavior

Tags: unit-testing, junit

One of the benefits of unit testing has always been as a sort of code documentation. It's possible for someone to look at the unit tests and see how the code should behave under different conditions.

What do people do when they want to express that the code behavior for given inputs is undefined? For example, you write a function that does not allow null as a value for it's first parameter.

```
// Yeah, this is overly simplistic, but the concept is there
public boolean isEmpty(String s) {
    return s.trim().length() == 0;
}
```

You want your unit tests, your "*live documentation*", to let the user know that null isn't a valid value for s, but you don't want to lock it down so that the current behavior for a null input is the only behavior allowed.

How do people generally handle this? The standard answer seems to be "don't test it", but that fights against the principle of using your unit tests as documentation (to some extent). Having some way to express it in the tests differentiates between "*I forgot about this case*" and "*I'm aware of this case, and the behavior is undefined*".

Tagging with junit because that's the framework I'm most interested in an answer for.

Comment: That function doesn't test for null and wont compile as you say your returning an int but return a boolean.

Comment: Why do you want undefined behavior? Why not have a specific behavior, such as it throws an `IllegalArgumentException`?

Comment: @David - Checking for valid inputs has a cost associated with it. Sometimes this is small, sometimes it's not. Either way, there are times it's not worth paying the cost.

Comment: "the code behavior for given inputs is undefined".  That's an epic design fail that unit testing (a) reveals and (b) allows you to fix.  Letting this bad design stand is crazy.

Comment: @S.Lott - Have to say I disagree completely. There are plenty of places where its reasonable to say "don't do that" so that you don't need to pay the cost of extra checks in the code. Internal/private functions that you may call in a tight loop, in particular, can generally do without the null check if you know you'll never pass in a null (though whether to test them is a whole different debate). Defensive coding is a good thing, but not always appropriate.

Comment: @RHSeeger: Wrong.  You don't need to attempt "defensive coding" to solve the problem.   You just run it and See what exception gets raised.  Document that exception in the test case.  This becomes the defined behavior, which is far, far better than having "undefined" behavior.

Comment: @S.Lott - That limits the changes you can make later, though. If you don't have an actual requirement for behavior, there's no reason to limit the function to it.

Comment: "If you don't have an actual requirement for behavior" you don't have  a very complete specification, and you have an epic design fail that needs to be fixed.  There's no reason to "limit" the functionality. You have a defined behavior which -- at some point -- may need to change.  The C-language "undefined behavior" is a terrible, terrible thing.  Not to be emulated or even considered as anything other than a gaping hole in the language run-time definition.

Comment: @S.Lott - We'll need to agree to disagree on this. Your opinion, and that's all it is, does not match mine. I firmly believe there are plenty of places where it's acceptable to not define behavior because that behavior doesn't matter at the moment _(ie, if you don't need a stable sort, there's no reason to define it **must** be unstable, you just **don't** define that it must be stable... then the implementation is free to go either way)_.

Comment: @RHSeeger: "then the implementation is free to go either way".  But.  Whatever way it does is (a) defined and (b) testable.  You're talking about an interface which leaves details undefined.  An implementation which leaves details undefined is an epic design failure.  Unusable.  Untrustworthy.  You can't tell a bug from a feature because it wasn't "defined".

Comment: @S.Lott - And, should you do that and define it as one way or the other, you're now bound to that decision later. Users of the function may have written code that relies on it acting that way, so you can't change it without possible impact to them. If you never defined it in the first place, then no code would have been written (hopefully) that relies on that behavior.

Comment: @RHSeeger: "If you never defined it in the first place" then code would explain whatever it turns out to do.  You're still bound by "undefined" because it does **something**.  Since it does **something** (even if you neglected to define that **something**) folks will write their own code and their own tests based on the **something** it actually did.  You're still bound to that legacy behavior and they still have to make changes.  It's better to define it and not have any of these problems.  Just avoid "undefined".  It's easy to do and your tests helped you do it.

Comment: @S.Lott - So, by that logic, if an API says it returns something that implements an interface, people can write code that then casts it to the specific class that the API uses and call methods on that. That's what the API does right now, so writing code that depends on it is to be expected and the developers of the API should assume changing the implementing class (in ways orthogonal to the interface) should be avoided. That's somewhat... ridiculous.

Comment: An API that implements an interface is a specific implementation with specific -- defined -- features that are testable.  Changing the implementing class in ways that are orthogonal to the interface cannot (by definition) change the interface test results.  The interface tests are focused on the **defined** behavior of the interface.  Other implementation test results are orthogonal to the interface and they -- of course -- change because the **defined** behavior of the implementation changed (and the interface didn't change.)  It's all defined, however.  Interface and implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test is *a* form of documentation, not *the* documentation. Using it as *a* form of documentation is good and great. Documenting undefined behaviour in unit tests is worse than dancing about your code - it just gives no information to the reader.

That said, the simplest live documentation for undefined behaviour is the precondition assertion (in the C sense), i.e. a precondition that is disabled in production code. It documents the boundaries of defined behaviour without producing runtime cost.

Comment: I'd argue that it does give information to the reader, that you didn't just forget that edge case, you've specifically declared it as undefined behavior. Working on the assumption that it's always possible to forget to test some things (ie. unit tests don't tell you your code is right, they just tell you where it's not wrong). That being said, your comment about "a documentation" vs. "the documentation" is a valid one. While it would be nice to have the tests convey the information, it might be better just leaving it in the usage documentation (ie, javadocs for my case).

Comment: Marking this one as the correct answer. While I would rather have seen an answer that showed a way to document that the case wasn't forgotten about in a unit test, I can certainly see the point that this information should be left to the actual documentation. Thanks much for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Unit tests define behavior.  If you want to say 'this function does not expect a null' then annotate your test method with `@Test(expected="Exception.class)`.

It makes no sense to test for undefined behavior.  All behavior that is not defined is by definition undefined.  So by defining it as undefined it will be defined to be undefined which it won't be once defined...**beep**...**error**...**logical inconsistency detected**.

Comment: The fact that the behavior is undefined means you can't test for an exception, since it's not determined to throw one.